# Docker's clang can not update

Tags: docker, clang, updates

I tried to compile code to ledger Nano S like there https://ledger.readthedocs.io/en/0/nanos/setup.html and I have a problem. When I run the "make .." command, it says "fno-jump-tables unknown argument". I see that it compiles by clang 3.9 but I download clang's latest version and link env variable to it like in the example. I have tried to download clang 6.0, 7.0, 4.0 and latest.

My question: how to update clang in docker to compile my code without error?

Comment: Edited for syntax and grammar.

Comment: Please add some more explanation. What did you do to install or update clang? (the setup page doesn't include clang setup, it is part of the docker image already). What is the exact `make` command that you ran? NOTE that Nano S SDK requires a special version of the clang compiler, as noted here: https://github.com/LedgerHQ/blue-devenv/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I saw that Nano S SDK requires special version of clang compiles i did it as in link.

Comment: I have tried "make", "make load" command, but an error "BOLOS_ENV and BOLOS_SDK not set" was found. It confused me because i had create environment variables "BOLOS_SDK" and "BOLOS_ENV" earlier. After i have tried "make BOLOS_ENV=/opt/ledger-blue/ BOLOS_SDK=/home/nanos-secure-sdk
" and it was errror "fno-jump-tables unknown argument"

Comment: To install clang i have downloaded LLVM, unpack it in folder2 which exist in folder1 which had linked earlier in BOLOS_ENV system variable ,rename folder2 to "clang-arm-fropi",  (do everything as there https://github.com/LedgerHQ/ledger-dev-doc/blob/master/source/userspace/getting_started.rst)

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the [guide](https://ledger.readthedocs.io/en/0/nanos/setup.html) you mentioned  and trying to compile `blue-app-helloworld` app you should take a look at its [Makefile](https://github.com/LedgerHQ/ledger-sample-apps/blob/master/blue-app-helloworld/Makefile) at first. At the [48th](https://github.com/LedgerHQ/ledger-sample-apps/blob/master/blue-app-helloworld/Makefile#L48) and the [60th](https://github.com/LedgerHQ/ledger-sample-apps/blob/master/blue-app-helloworld/Makefile#L60) lines you'll see the path it looks for `clang` binaries. So, if you want to use different version of `clang` for the build process you could do the following:

1. Install clang-4.0 as it's described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1280068/how-do-i-install-clang-4-0-on-ubuntu-14-04). Before that you'll need to pre-install some [default packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593433/error-sudo-add-apt-repository-command-not-found)
2. Edit the Makefile:

   The 48th line should be set to: `CLANGPATH := /usr/bin/`

   The 60th line should be set to: `CC := $(CLANGPATH)clang-4.0`
3. Run the build as it's described in the guide by executing:
   `make BOLOS_ENV=/opt/ledger-blue/ BOLOS_SDK=/home/nanos-secure-sdk`

You'll see `app.elf` and `app.hex` files in the bin folder.